# How to create auto resizing empty div between min-height and max-height css?

Tags: css, height, autoresize

html has empty div, I need to auto resize div to max height for the breakpoint

```
div {
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 400px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just set its `height` to `100vh`:

```css
div {
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```